# pip install pylbfgs fails in a clean virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, cython, cythonize, python-dedupe

On a completely fresh virtualenv, installing `pylbfgs` fails with the error below. My goal is to install `dedupe`, but it depends on `pylbfgs`.

I'm assuming it has something to do with the release of Cython 3.0.0 a few days ago, but even if I do `pip install Cython==0.29.35` it still fails. Last commit to `pylbfgs` was in 2014 so something external must have changed.

Any idea how I can set up an environment to make it work?

```
$ pip install pylbfgs
Collecting pylbfgs
  Using cached PyLBFGS-0.2.0.14.tar.gz (98 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [57 lines of output]
      /private/var/folders/jg/pb4kddl17kzf4njpdp3ht8rh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-rhor0rp4/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:381: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: /private/var/folders/jg/pb4kddl17kzf4njpdp3ht8rh0000gn/T/pip-install-hgmjirii/pylbfgs_27ac07c00d1741aaa6fb205fbf713b21/lbfgs/_lowlevel.pyx
        tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...

              x_a = aligned_copy(x0.ravel())

              try:
                  callback_data = (f, progress, x0.shape, args)
                  r = lbfgs(n, x_a, fx_final, call_eval,
                                              ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      lbfgs/_lowlevel.pyx:395:40: Cannot assign type 'lbfgsfloatval_t (void *, lbfgsconst_p, lbfgsfloatval_t *, int, lbfgsfloatval_t) except? -1' to 'lbfgs_evaluate_t'

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
              x_a = aligned_copy(x0.ravel())

              try:
                  callback_data = (f, progress, x0.shape, args)
                  r = lbfgs(n, x_a, fx_final, call_eval,
                            call_progress, <void *>callback_data, &self.params)
                            ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      lbfgs/_lowlevel.pyx:396:22: Cannot assign type 'int (void *, lbfgsconst_p, lbfgsconst_p, lbfgsfloatval_t, lbfgsfloatval_t, lbfgsfloatval_t, lbfgsfloatval_t, int, int, int) except? -1' to 'lbfgs_progress_t'
      Compiling lbfgs/_lowlevel.pyx because it changed.
      [1/1] Cythonizing lbfgs/_lowlevel.pyx
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/_/dev/test/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/_/dev/test/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/_/dev/test/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/jg/pb4kddl17kzf4njpdp3ht8rh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-rhor0rp4/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/jg/pb4kddl17kzf4njpdp3ht8rh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-rhor0rp4/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/jg/pb4kddl17kzf4njpdp3ht8rh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-rhor0rp4/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/jg/pb4kddl17kzf4njpdp3ht8rh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-rhor0rp4/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 27, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/jg/pb4kddl17kzf4njpdp3ht8rh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-rhor0rp4/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1134, in cythonize
          cythonize_one(*args)
        File "/private/var/folders/jg/pb4kddl17kzf4njpdp3ht8rh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-rhor0rp4/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1301, in cythonize_one
          raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
      Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: lbfgs/_lowlevel.pyx
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Same problem with this more recent fork: https://github.com/dedupeio/pylbfgs

Comment: There also a related discussion going on here https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/600

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to Python <3.11 seems to work (verified with v3.10.12). Not an ideal solution though.